# Plpgsql : non recursive category tree function doesn't return any rows :(

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

So, here's the function that would return the products  of a given category and its child categories. Its a 3 level tree. The function is fine, but when i run it, it says 0 rows returned. Any ideas?

EDIT: parents1 and parents2 are supposed to be arrays of the children of the parent category. Parents1 children of $1 , and parents2 children of all parents1 nodes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ecommerce.select_products_by_category(par bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF ecommerce.product AS
$BODY$ 
declare 
    result ecommerce.product;
    parents bigint[];
    parents2 bigint[];
    i int;
begin 
        parents := array(
        select category_id from ecommerce.category where parent_id = par
        );
        return query select * from ecommerce.product where category_id = par;
        for i in 1..array_upper(parents,1)
        loop 
            return query select * from ecommerce.product where category_id = parents[i];
            raise notice 'p %',parents[i];

        end loop;

        for i in 1..array_upper(parents,1) 
        loop 
            parents2  := array(
            select category_id from ecommerce.category where parent_id = parents[i] 
                );
        end loop;
        for i in 1..array_upper(parents2,1)
        loop 
            return query select * from ecommerce.product where category_id = parents2[i];
            raise notice 'p2 %',parents2[i];

    end loop; 

    --return query theset;

end ; $BODY$
```

and this is how i run it

```
SELECT * From ecommerce.select_products_by_category(
    1
);
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply using a recursive common table expression? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code cannot to work. The result of table function is related with any individual CALL of table function, not with global CALL of table function. Any table returning recursive function have to have use a pattern:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_parent_id integer)
RETURNS TABLE (node_id integer, node_val, parent_id integer) AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR node_id, node_val, parent_id IN
      SELECT f.node_id, f.node_val, f.parent_id
         FROM footab f
        WHERE f.parent_id = _parent_id
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT;

    /*
     * Copy result of recursive call to function result
     */
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM foo(node_id);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When you use [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html), then then you can get result little bit faster and the code will be more readable:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
     SELECT node_id, node_val, parent_id FROM footab
       WHERE parent_id = <<root_id>>
     UNION ALL
     SELECT node_id, node_val, parent_id FROM footab, t
       WHERE footab.parent_id = t.id
) SELECT * FROM t;
```